# How to correctly implement a confimation window using jquery, html and the twitter bootstrap framework

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

im using the twitter bootstrap framework and im a little confuse triyng to implement correctly a [modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal) (a confirmation window).

The thing is, at the moment my site renders a table with links, ammong each link there is a "delete button", when the user hits it they go to another page asking for confirmation, the button to confirm is just a link like `delete.php?ref=THE-LINK`. The string *THE-LINK* is just an unique id passed by jquery in order to identify what link to delete:

```
$('.remove_link').live('click', function(e) {   window.location = 'delete.php?ref=' + $(this).attr('id');  });
```

Ok, now i dont want the user to go from the *table* page to the *delete* page, i want to use a modal. The twitter modal works very easy, just including the html for the format and the javascript:

```
<script src="JS/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
          <div id="modal-from-dom" class="modal hide fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
              <h3>Delete URL</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>You are about to delete one track url, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
              <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <a href="delete.php?confirm=yes&ref=THE-URL" class="btn danger">Yes</a>
              <a href="#" class="btn secondary">No</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Then you can fire it up just by: `$('#modal-from-dom').modal('show');` . The thing is, how can i pass the id *THE-URL* to the modal in order to make it dynamic, because at this point the modal ask me for two options (links, yes or no) but the links have to be dynamics, has to change depending of the id of the delete button (`$(#remove_link).attr('id')`) who call it. So how can i make this work? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/MjmVr/1/ 
It's not ideal but do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic modal in this way

Assume you have an index value with identifier `i` 
and a unique `ID` for every record.

Put the id value on the span attribute

(I show this in jsp syntax):

```
  <c:forEach items="${elements}" var="element" varStatus="i">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value='${element}' /></td>
      <td>
        <div class="center">
        <span id='${element["ID"]}'>
            <a href='#deleteElement' data-toggle="modal" >
              <i class="icon-trash"></i>
            </a>
        </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

define your form modal

```
<form action="/submitUserDeleteUrl" 
      id="submitDelete">       
    <hidden name="id">
    <div id="deleteElement" class="modal hide fade">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >&times;</a>
          <h3>delete form</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p>do you want to cancel element: </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">
        CANCEL
        </a>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="OK"/>                                                       
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

add the jQuery setup after document ready. This just binds to
every link for the modal the injection of parameters retrieved by the `span`

```
jQuery('#yourtableid a[data-toggle|="modal"]').on('click', function () {
    var id=jQuery(this).parent('span').attr('id');
    jQuery('#deleteElement').one('show', function () {
        //here made simple, you should append
        jQuery(this).find('.modal-body p').text(id); 
        var action = jQuery(this).parent('form').attr('action');
        //shouldn't because there is a hidden in the form anyway check it out
        jQuery(this).parent('form').attr('action', action+'?id='+id);
    });
});
```